# Apache + PHP-FRM, php_value statements in a pool

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I run several small websites using named virtual hosts, with Apache/mod_php.
After moving to a new machine last week, I discovered that Apache/PHP-FPM had been installed. I'm now faced with the task of migrating all the sites from using .htaccess to using pools.

I cannot figure out how to "translate" the .htaccess format `php_value include_path "/home/user/WebSites/mySite.org/src/php"` to one which PHP-FPM pools will use.
The declarations in the test pool are parsed and set - but not used. After two solid days, I'm no nearer to a solution.

In index.html:

```
echo ">> get_include_path = " . get_include_path();
```

produces:

```
get_include_path = /home/user/WebSites/mySite.org/php
```

but `php_admin_value[auto-prepend_file]` and `php_admin_value[auto-append_file]` are ignored.

`$ status php-fpm` shows the default pool "www" and the test pool "mySite" are loaded and running.

I really hope someone can point me to the solution before I go completely nuts.

Apologies for posting an image of the relevant bits of code, but I could not get the markdown editor to accept a simple <pre>...</pre> around it.

[image: details]

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I found the problem, which was a typo:
`php_admin_value[auto-prepend_file]` and `php_admin_value[auto-append_file]`
should be
`php_admin_value[auto_prepend_file]` and `php_admin_value[auto_append_file]`
ie. I had a dash instead of an underscore.